# Need a sharepoint 2010 webpart to have editable GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview, sharepoint-2010

I am a new sharepoint developer and trying to create webpart from VS2012 with sharepoint project workspace.

I have the below code in my workspace and want to show results in data grid view where i need last 2 columns to be editable. And then I need to submit the data to the sharepoint list.

```
 protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            // Define the grid control that displays employee data in the Web Part.
            grid = new DataGrid();
            grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            grid.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
            grid.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "ms-vh2";
            grid.CellPadding = 2;
            grid.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(5);
            grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            grid.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

            // Populate the grid control with data in the employee data file. 
            try
            {

                var dataEndPoint = new Uri("http://<ServerName>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc");
                var dc = new TeamSiteDataContext(dataEndPoint);
                dc.Credentials = CredentialCache
                    .DefaultNetworkCredentials;
----
```

When I add the gridview to the Controls collection - ie Controls.Add(grid), I do not have control about which columns are editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPGridView to achieve that, here is an example
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16